# VBScript - Conditional Replacement Regex

Tags: vbscript

In a text file, I want to remove all Carriage Returns (vbCrLf) except those vbCrLf that are preceded by a period (.)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, no regex is needed.

Open the text file, split the entire text contents on what you want to retain (to create an array), then loop through the array and replace want you don't want during the file rewrite, ensuring to append what you wanted to retain.

For example:

```
Dim retain : retain = "." & vbCrLf
Dim toss : toss = vbCrLf

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim txtFile
    With .OpenTextFile("C:\TestFile.txt", 1, False)
        txtFile = Split(.ReadAll(), retain)
        .Close
    End With

    With .OpenTextFile("C:\NewTestFile.txt", 2, True)
        Dim row
        For Each row In txtFile
            .Write Replace(row, toss, " ") & retain
        Next
        .Close
    End With
End With
```

Truth be told, VBScript's RegExp Pattern syntax may not be robust enough -- due to lack of look-ahead patterns -- to handle your conditional criteria cleanly with a single pass.